# Where is the Safari's History.plist file in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios

I need my Safari history from the backed up file in iTunes.  I was able to extract the backup data but in iOS 7 there is only Bookmarks.db in the directory.

It not in here anymore?

> /Library/Safari/History.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari history file from iOS backup can be found as ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/[DEVICE GUID]/ed50eadf14505ef0b433e0c4a380526ad6656d3a .
Copy it, rename it as [something].plist and open it with plist viewer.

Also Bookmarks.db is d1f062e2da26192a6625d968274bfda8d07821e4 in the backup folder, RecentSearches.plist is 37d957bda6d8be85555e7c0a7d30c5a8bc1b5cce.

Answer (score 1):

The history file has changed in iOS 8 to ed50eadf14505ef0b433e0c4a380526ad6656d3a

And here is the command to generate that UUID:

echo -n AppDomain-com.apple.mobilesafari-Library/Safari/History.plist | shasum

Other files can be found in the manifest, join the domain and the path with a dash.